# Mixed model gives random effects with high variance. What should I do?

Tags: panel-data, time-varying-covariate

What do you do when you have observational hierarchical data and the random effects of a mixed model have really high variance?

Some things I have considered are:

1. Picking groups that have low in the response. And using only those in the analysis. This has the downside of loss of replicates.
2. Currently the response is "change" with possible range of [-$\infty$,$\infty$]. I have considered changing the response from continuous to dichotomous. For example, given a certain threshold the response would be 1 else 0. This has the obvious downside of losing information in the form of magnitude.
3. Same as two, but taking it one step further and collapsing the levels with dichotomous responses into proportions and repeating all the way up the levels until I can do multiple logistic regression. This is bad with great loss in information, but I would be lying if I said I had not considered it.

Edit:To add a little more detail about my data -- while still hoping this question is general enough to help more people in similar situations-- my data has the following structure.

There are many areas. Each area has many units, each unit is measured repeatedly over time. Each area is exposed to many effects. The question is about what effects are most important to causing the outcome to increase over time.

Comment: Why, in your mind, do you need to do anything? Is it a problem for you that the random effects have high variance?

Comment: It seems that having random effects that have variances orders of magnitude larger than fixed effects is a bad thing. Wouldn't that mean that the model does not have a good fit? I guess my questions is what happens as the variance of the random effects approach infinity? Maybe I don't understand how to interpret the variances of the random effects. How do I know if my mixed effects model is a bad fit?